# Getting the select box option value in a form if the submit button of a particular form is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of forms on one page without a form name.

Each form has a select box and a submit button. Whenever the button is clicked I need to get the value of the select box for the particular form where the button was clicked

form example

```
<form>
<select class="boxes" name="select3">
   <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" align="right" class="btn" value="Add to basket" name="submit">
</form>
```

**My code thus far**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
                       if($(this).val() == 'Add to basket'){
                           var value = $('select[value="select3"] option:selected').val();
                           alert(value);
                           return false;
                       }
                    });
```

All forms look the same just with a couple of more fields and different values in the select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
var value = $('select.boxes option:selected').val();
```

or

```
var value = $('select[name="select3"] option:selected').val();
```

instead of

```
var value = $('select[value="select3"] option:selected').val();
```

if you wanna make it more unique, give it an ID..

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(this).parent().find(".boxes")
```

for accessing the select box of the particlular form.

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Add to basket') {
        var value = $(this).parent().find('.boxes').val();
        alert(value);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Add to basket') {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var value = $('select[value="select3"]', form).val();
        alert(value);
        return false;
    }
});
```